# Checking for spelling errors with a trie

Tags: c++, c++14, trie

I have been lately working in my C++, and I finished up this trie, and I want to know how my C++ is looking so far.

**Node.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

static const int ALPHABETSIZE = 26;

struct Node {
    bool isEnd;
    int prefixCount;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> child[ALPHABETSIZE];
};
```

**Trie.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "Node.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Trie {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> head;

public:
    Trie();

    void insert(const std::string& word) const;
    bool search(const std::string& word) const;

    unsigned int wordsWithPrefix(const std::string& prefix) const;
};
```

**Trie.cpp**

```
#include "Trie.hpp"

Trie::Trie() {
    head = std::make_unique<Node>();
    head->isEnd = false;
    head->prefixCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABETSIZE; ++i) {
        head->child[i] = nullptr;
    }
}

void Trie::insert(const std::string& word) const{
    auto current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
        int letter = word[i] - 'a';
        if (!current->child[letter])
            current->child[letter] = std::make_shared<Node>();
        current->child[letter]->prefixCount++;
        current = current->child[letter];
    }

    current->isEnd = true;
}

bool Trie::search(const std::string& word) const{
    auto current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
        auto letter = word[i] - 'a';
        if (!current->child[letter])
            return false;
        current = current->child[letter];
    }

    return current->isEnd;
}

unsigned int Trie::wordsWithPrefix(const std::string& prefix) const{
    auto current = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < prefix.length(); ++i) {
        auto letter = prefix[i] - 'a';
        if (!current->child[letter])
            return 0;
        current = current->child[letter];
    }
    return current->prefixCount;
}
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Trie.hpp"

int main() {
    Trie trie;
    std::ifstream file;
    std::string word = " ", input;

    file.open("dictionary.txt");

    //Ask for input
    std::cin >> input;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::tolower);

    auto beenHere = false;
    //Add every word to the trie.
    while (std::getline(file, word)) {
        std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
        //if word's first character equals to input's, go on, else, dont add it onto the trie.
        if (word[0] == input[0]){
            beenHere = true;
            trie.insert(word);  
        }
        //If you've already been on the word's first character
        //, and it isn't the same as the input's you are done.
        if (beenHere && word[0] != input[0]) break;
    }

    std::string x = "";
    for (int i = 0, length = input.length(); i < length; ++i) {
        x += input.at(i);
        if (trie.wordsWithPrefix(x) == 0) {
            std::cout << x << "<" << input.substr(i+1, length - 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Node**

Raw arrays:

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> child[ALPHABETSIZE];
```

are really awkward. There's little reason to prefer to use one here. Use a `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<std::shared_ptr<Node>, ALPHABETSIZE> children;
```

Also I pluralized your array name. Seems to make more sense. You also want to make sure that a default-constructed `Node` is valid, so I find it clearer to just add data member initializers:

```
struct Node {
    bool isEnd = false;
    int prefixCount = 0;
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<Node>, ALPHABETSIZE> children;
};
```

Now you don't have to worry about default/value initialization.

You current construct your `head` via:

```
head = std::make_unique<Node>();
```

But `head` is a `shared_ptr` so you should do:

```
head = std::make_shared<Node>();
```

And with the added data member initializers, that's all we need to do in our constructor. Done!

**insertion**

Prefer a range-based for loop anytime you want to loop over everything in a container without needing the iterator. It expresses intent better:

```
for (char c : word) {
    int letter = c - 'a';
    ...
}
```

Also, what if `word` contains anything other than a lower-case letter? What if it's a capital letter or a space or a hyphen? This does no error checking here, so leaves open the possibility of undefined behavior due to invalid memory access.

**Choice of data structure**

Does having 26 children for each node make sense? That could be very memory intensive if our data set is sparse! I'd expect something more like:

```
std::unordered_map<char, std::shared_ptr<Node>>
```

with which this would just look like:

```
auto& next = current->children[letter];
if (!next) next = std::make_shared<Node>();
next->prefixCount++;
current = next;
```

**searching**

I would rename `search()` to `contains()`, and same points apply about sanity checking your inputs and using a range-based for loop.

**wordsWithPrefix**

Note that your `search` and `wordsWithPrefix` do the same thing: we walk the length of the string, break early if we run out of children, and do something with the result. That suggests adding a helper function:

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> atPrefix(const std::string& prefix) const;
```

which does that work for us. With that function, we can implement:

```
bool contains(const std::string& word) const
{
    auto node = atPrefix(word);
    return node && node->isEnd;
}

unsigned int wordsWithPrefix(const std::string& prefix) const
{
    auto node = atPrefix(prefix);
    return node ? node->prefixCount : 0;
}
```

**Trie construction**

You may want to add a constructor that will iterate over and insert a bunch of words. Maybe take two iterators, same as the other standard containers.

**cin and getline**

Be careful about [mixing those two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input). It doesn't always work.

Also, don't do this:

```
std::string word = " ", input;
```

Space isn't at a premium, you can declare your variables on separate lines.

**main()**

What is `input`? I don't understand your usage here. Are you mandating a sorted `dictionary.txt` for this to work? Some comments indicating this would be helpful.

**final loop**

`at()` vs `operator[]` just does range-checking. You don't need that here, so simply use `operator[]`. Also if what you want to do is divide `input`, you don't need a second argument to `substr()` - just the one will automatically print the remainder of the string from there on out. Besides, your length argument is incorrect anyway.

Prefer:

```
std::string x;
for (char c : input) {
    x += c;
    if (trie.wordsWithPrefix(x) == 0) {
        std::cout << x << '<' << input.substr(x.size());
        break;
    }
}
```

**file.close()**

Unnecessary. The `ifstream` destructor will take care of itself. RAII for the win.

Comment: Wow, that is an amazing review. If @Barry were my colleague reviewing my code, I would be the happiest programmer around.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
All of what you said worked flawlessly, again, thanks.

After changing my code a little bit more, it now works with a capital letters and hyphens. [Here's my code if you want to check it out](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5605725ec7e5ecf971c2) I do believe there's some memory leaking somewhere, but I can't find where...

Anyways, thanks!